Vercel deployment error: "rename '/vercel/path0/.next/export/500.html' -> '/vercel/path0/.next/server/pages/500.html"
Anyone have this issue with deployment to Vercel? It seems to have come out of nowhere... I'm using Next.js 14.2.4. (latest)
I was told:

"restart your npm and clear npm cache
delete your build cache too"

I've deleted node modules, package.lock, and .next. I did npm update. and ran `npm cache clean --force... No fix. I then went to Vercel's project settings > Data Cache > purge everything & attepted to redeploy, and i'm still getting the same error. Am I missing something? Thanks!

